# Reactjs AdSense change format in a one-page app

Tags: reactjs, adsense

I add some Google AdSense in the website I'm developing and I'm having some issues. They are inserted and they are looking great! My website is a One-Page App, so it is never reloaded.

The problem start when I click on a link (to open another section of the website) and come back to the previous one. The last AdSense of the page is taking the format of another ad from the page.

Example, I have ads with those format : rectangle 336x250 and lower in the page I have a banner 728x90.
When I change section on the website then come back, the rectangle is the same, but the ad in the banner (which is still 728x90) becamed 336x250.

Apparently, Google AdSense can be strange if we use a third party Javascript
Anyone would have an idea to how to correct this?

Here's the render function of my class AdSense

```
render() {
    const margin = this.props.margin === undefined ? 0 : this.props.margin;
    const display = this.props.display === undefined ? 'inline-block' : this.props.display;

    const style = {
        display: display,
        width: this.props.width,
        height: this.props.height,
        margin: margin
    };
    return (
        <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <ins
                className="adsbygoogle"
                style={style}
                data-ad-client="ca-pub-2057811794476296"
                data-ad-slot={this.props.slot} />
        </div>
    );
}`
```